# Symfony2 forms - embedded form embeds inside bootstrap form-group

Tags: forms, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using BraincraftedBootstrapBundle and run into a small issue using embedding forms.

Assuming I build the form using builder as follows:

```
$builder->add('title', 'text', ...)
    ->add('name', 'text', ...)
    ->add('address', new AddressType(), array('label' => false);
```

When the form is created, all the fields are placed in form-groups as per bootstrap but the entire address form is also placed in a form-group, eg:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-3"><label>Title</label></div>
    <div class="col-lg-9"><input ....></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-lg-3"><label>Name</label></div>
    <div class="col-lg-9"><input ....></div>
</div>

-- but then the entire embedded address form is placed in a form-group ---

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-lg-3"><label>Address</label></div>
           <div class="col-lg-9"><input ....></div>
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-lg-3"><label>City</label></div>
           <div class="col-lg-9"><input ....></div>
        </div> 
        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-lg-3"><label>State</label></div>
           <div class="col-lg-9"><input ....></div>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I stop the embedded form from being embedded within a form group?

**Edit**
If this can't be changed, how do you change the column size for the outer div wrapping the address form? Eg from col-lg-9 to col-lg-12? I tried adding 'attr' => array('widget-col' => 12) to the address but that sets it for all elements within the address form

Comment: Solved - see answer below....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question but after a lot of research, I finally found the answer thanks to help from this link:

http://blog.bouzekri.net/2015/02/06/symfony-tips-find-form-theme-override-block-name/

From this I was able to see what blocks were being created by twig and therefore could override the form_row block:

```
 {% block _xxxxxxx_publicbundle_address_block_row %}
        <div class="address_group">
                {{ block('form_input_group') }}
                {{ form_errors(form) }}            
        </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

So there you have it, quite simple. I posted this as an answer so others may save a bit of time....